# Database ERD design: 2 types user in one table

Tags: database, entity-relationship, erd

I have read this ([Database design: 3 types of users, separate or one table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8479252/database-design-3-types-of-users-separate-or-one-table))

I decided to put admin and normal user in one table since the attributes are similar:

- fullname,
- address,
- phone,
- email,
- gender
- ...

Then I want to draw ERD, suddenly my mind pop out a question.
How to draw?

Customer make appointment and admin approve appointment.
now only two tables.
Help.

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8113064/1248931

Answer (score 0):

Employee Table - Customers Table - appointment Table
Self join relationship Employee Has manager Id